# country helper not displaying from template

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a [bootstrap form helper](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country) jquery plugin to help users pick a country and see the flags.

I have an ember application with all of my templates in `index.html`
When I put the desired html

`<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="RW" data-flags="true"></div>`

into the index file I get the appropriate dropdown.

[image]

When I put the same html inside a template, say 'about'

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
<h3>About</h3>
<p>This is a basic application using Ember.js on the client side</p>
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="RW" data-flags="true"></div>
</script>
```

The code will not display when I direct to `index.html#/about` by clicking a link. The div shows in the console but the styles do not display, it's invisible. Strangely when I refresh the `index.html#/about` the country picker displays.

How can I get this div to consistently display?

Answer (score 0):

You should def and AboutView and add code to the didInsertElement hook

```
App.AboutView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$('form select.bfh-countries, span.bfh-countries, div.bfh-countries').each(function () {
          var $countries;
          $countries = $(this);
          if ($countries.hasClass('bfh-selectbox')) {
            $countries.bfhselectbox($countries.data());
          }
          $countries.bfhcountries($countries.data());
        });
    }
});
```

Good Luck

Comment: The code is extracted from here... https://github.com/vlamanna/BootstrapFormHelpers/blob/master/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.js#L190-L200 and adapted to ember view